# \includeonly not working as expected with newclude

Tags: latex, miktex

In LaTeX, the \includeonly statement exists to selectively add or exclude sub-documents.

One *quirk* in the whole process is that when sections are excluded, LaTeX decides to insert a page-break. The article at [To have no pagebreak after \include in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209065/to-have-no-pagebreak-after-include-in-latex) recommends using newclude to avoid this issue.  This package defines \include* which provides a work-around by omitting the implied \clearpage.

I am occasionally seeing the behaviour where if I comment out lines of my \includeonly statement the sub-document still gets included.  Has anyone else seen this behaviour?

Comment: 1. I would hardly call it a 'bug' as all the documentation says that \includeonly works by going \clearpage \input \clearpage. Clearly this is how the package is supposed to work.

2. It's VERY HARD to troubleshoot a latex question without some sort of example code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: No.. certainly it's not a bug in LaTeX... it's introduced by the newclude package.

What I need is something like (in pseudoTeX):

IfIncluded{technicalsection.tex}{
\input{technicalsection.tex}
}

Comment: I've changed bug to *quirk* as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, everything is now working as it should.

Just in case the order of the \usepackage directives is important, in the working version \usepackage{newclude} is the first command after \documentclass{article}.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, it's a feature.  Really.  Does \input do what you need, rather than \include?

Comment: \input would work fine, except that \input generates an error if the file doesn't exist (as in I haven't written it yet). Also, after I've written a complete document, it's sometimes nice to remove the technical sections if asked to produce a management-level version.  \includeonly should do exactly that, but NOT if I \usepackage{newclude}.

Getting rid of the \clearpage is a nice feature, but not if it breaks \includeonly.